# Bootstrap menu not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a wordpress site that I am coding using Bootstrap 5 which works for everything except the navbar which does not expand when clicked as a hamburger, tried a few solutions online, changed CDN, class name changes for Bootstrap 5 etc but still not working, not sure if I have bootstrap installed as well as CDN that might be causing an issue as I started this build a long time ago, code below. Appreciate any help anyone can give me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <?php wp_head();?>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .topnav #myLinks {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .topnav a.icon {
    background: #0178c4;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
    text-transform: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
  }
  
  .active {
    background-color: #0178c4;
    color: white;
  }
  
  #myLinks a {
    background-color: #0178c4;
  }
  
  #myLinks a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(1, 120, 196, 0.7) !important;
  }
  /* Icon 3 */
  
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 18px;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 36px;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0;
    left: 50%;
  }
  
  .header-logo {
    max-width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url();?>" class="active"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images\m-no-shadow.png');?>" class="header-logo"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/about-us">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/contact-us">Contact us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/reviews">Reviews</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: did you add bootstrap 5 css? `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: also, element `<a class="navbar-brand" ... class="active">` duplicate attribute `class` is present

Comment: there's no element `#myLinks` in your markup, this will not work: `var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `id` for your navbar is **navbarNav**, replace **myLinks** in your JS function with **navbarNav** and also add `onclick` event to your navbar toggler which calls your `myFunction()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <?php wp_head();?>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .topnav #myLinks {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .topnav a.icon {
    background: #0178c4;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
    text-transform: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
  }
  
  .active {
    background-color: #0178c4;
    color: white;
  }
  
  #myLinks a {
    background-color: #0178c4;
  }
  
  #myLinks a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(1, 120, 196, 0.7) !important;
  }
  /* Icon 3 */
  
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 18px;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 36px;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  #nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0;
    left: 50%;
  }
  
  .header-logo {
    max-width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url();?>" class="active"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images\m-no-shadow.png');?>" class="header-logo"></a>
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/about-us">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/contact-us">Contact us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/reviews">Reviews</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("navbarNav");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```